# write a list as element in data frame in r

Tags: r, list

I would like to make an empty data frame with 2 columns, named "ngrams" and "pred".

```
df <- data.frame(nGrams=character(), pred = character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I need each element in column "pred" to be a vector of words, but if I initialize 'pred = list()' the data frame won't add that column in.

I tried

```
> pred
[1] "a"    "the"  "not"  "that" "to"   "an"  

df[nrow(df)+1, ] <- c("is", pred)

Error in matrix(value, n, p) : 
  (converted from warning) data length [7] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns [2]

df[nrow(df)+1, ] <- c("the", list(pred))

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, nrow(df) + 1, , value = list("the",  : 
      (converted from warning) replacement element 2 has 6 rows to replace 1 rows
```

Can anyone show me what is the right way of doing it? Thanks in advance.

EDIT

I got the solution using data.table

```
dt <- data.table(nGrams = my_ngrams, pred = list_pred)
```

where list_pred is a list of lists. But it's still good to know the right way for data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
 d1 <- data.frame(nGrams='the', pred=I(list(pred)))
 str(d1)
 #'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
 #$ nGrams: Factor w/ 1 level "the": 1
 #$ pred  :List of 1
 # ..$ : chr  "a" "the" "not" "that" ...
 #..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

Or using the empty dataframe `df`

```
 df[nrow(df)+1,] <- list('is', list(pred))
 str(df)
 #'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
 #$ nGrams: chr "is"
 #$ pred  :List of 1
 # ..$ : chr  "a" "the" "not" "that" ...
```

where,

```
pred <- c('a', 'the', 'not', 'that', 'to', 'an')
```